# Get List from Preferences Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a program that retrieves a list of saved addresses from a database and should save it in Preferences. Then get that list to check if the current location of the user matches one of the addresses in the list, if so then start an other background service.

It seems like when I try to save the list in Preferences something goes wrong. Because when I run the app I get a null response.

This is the Task that retrieves the list of  addresses from the database:

```
public async static Task GetAddress()
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> keys = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"username", Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get(Strings.KEY_USERNAME,null) }

        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keys);
        var response = await Constants.client.PostAsync(Strings.URL_GETADDRESS, content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String: " + responseString);
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
            var addressList = new List<string>(SavedPreferences.AddressList);

            if (!jObj.GetBoolean("error"))
            {
                JSONArray array = jObj.GetJSONArray("addresses");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject address = array.GetJSONObject(i);
                    addressList.Add(address.GetString("address"));

                }

                SavedPreferences.AddressList = addressList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            Crashes.TrackError(exception);
        }
    }
```

This is saves in Preferences:

```
static T Deserialize<T>(string serializedObject) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
static string Serialize<T>(T objectToSerialize) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);

public static List<string> AddressList
        {
            get
            {
            var savedList = Deserialize<List<string>>(Preferences.Get(nameof(AddressList), null));
            return savedList ?? new List<string>();
        }

        set
        {
            var serializedList = Serialize(value);
            Preferences.Set(nameof(AddressList), serializedList);
        }

    }
}
```

This checks for matches in the list:

```
var GetList = new List<string>(SavedPreferences.AddressList);
                            var address = placemark.Thoroughfare + " " + placemark.SubThoroughfare;
                            
                            foreach(string item in GetList)
                            {
                                if (item.Contains(address))
                                {
                                    var startMessage = new StartWorkoutMessage();
                                    MessagingCenter.Send(startMessage, "StartWorkout");
                                    await SecureStorage.SetAsync(Constants.WORKOUT_STATUS_KEY, "1");
                                }
                                    
                            }
```

And this is the Stacktrace:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities
ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull (System.Object value, System.String parameterName)
Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
Newtonsoft.Json
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value)
Marongo.Utils
SavedPreferences.Deserialize[T] (System.String serializedObject) C:\Users\sebas\source\repos\Marongo\Marongo\Utils\SavedPreferences.cs:12
Marongo.Utils
SavedPreferences.get_AddressList () C:\Users\sebas\source\repos\Marongo\Marongo\Utils\SavedPreferences.cs:36
Marongo.Utils
DatabaseTasks.GetAddress () C:\Users\sebas\source\repos\Marongo\Marongo\Utils\DatabaseTasks.cs:70
```

Comment: Preferences is intended for use with basic data types.  Stuffing an entire json array in it is possible, but it sounds like your serialize/deserialize logic is faulty.

Comment: Okey, I will look closer on that. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @SebastianG So you have any ways to solve your problem?

Comment: @Cherry Bu Havent had time to look at it yet, if I find a soloution I will post it here.